# MWPhotoBrowser add data from plist?

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsarray, plist

trying to get some data from a plist into the [MWPhotoBrowser](http://michaelwaterfall.com/post/3621813945/mwphotobrowser-a-simple-ios-photo-browser) sample app.

Any ideas how to do it?

```
UIViewController *converterController = nil;
    NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    converterController = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithPhotos:photos];
    converterController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

//here individual images can be added. However need to add images from a plist.

    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image2" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image3" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image4" ofType:@"jpg"]]];


    if (converterController) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:converterController animated:YES];

        [converterController release];

    }
    [photos release];
```

Can add objects individually as shown above, but not able to do it with a plist.

Can anyone share an idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w
ell i got this but it doesnt work.

```
SString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
        @"ImageData" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Build the array from the plist  
  photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

crashes the app.
I must use the MWPhoto property.

Help anyone?
Maybe Michael Waterfall wants to look into this?

EDIT:

OK here is the working code (well it works ok so far)

```
 NSUInteger nimages = 0;
    for (; ; nimages++) {

        NSString *nameOfImage_ = @"imageSufix";

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.jpg", nameOfImage_, (nimages + 1)];
        //NSLog(@"Name is %@", imageName); log the names

        image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        if (image == nil) {
            break;
        }

    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithImage:image]];
```